# Pass A Value From Ajax Call To Index Method

Tags: ajax, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, controller

I've a requirement where I've to return an id from Ajax call to Index method of the `HomeController' and I can pass the id to the controller with Ajax as follows:

**Update 1**:

**ProductRating Class**:

```
public class ProductRating
{
   public int ProductId { get; set; }
   public string ProductName { get; set; }
   public double UserRating { get; set; }
   public double? RatingCount { get; set; } //Messed up with this earlier and when Luqman told me about the model, it reminded to add this property and the rest is done 
   public double? Total { get; set; }
}
```

**Ajax Call**:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function (response) {
     if (response) {
       $.ajax({
          url: '@Url.Action("AddRating")',
          data: { id: '@item.ProductId', rating: rate },
          type: 'POST',
          success: function (data) {
                 $('.@item.ProductId').html(data);
                   }
                });
              }
          }).fail(function () {
        alert("Failed to get total ratings!");
     });
</script>
```

**Controller**:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddRating(int id, double rating)
{
   var con = new ProductRating
   {
      RatingCount = db.Ratings.Where(c => c.ProductId == id).Count()
   };

   if (con.RatingCount >= 300)
   {
      return Json("Rating limit already exits", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
   else
   {
      Ratings aRatings = new Ratings();
      aRatings.ProductId = id;
      aRatings.UserRating = rating;

      db.Ratings.Add(aRatings);
      db.SaveChanges();

      return Json(con.RatingCount, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
}
```

See in the above method, I've set the id into a session variable and would pass this variable value into the Index method as a parameter. The problem is the session variable doesn't work in the first attempt until I refresh the page. But while debugging, I can see the values and every time, it gets erased. I guess, that isn't the correct way to do so. `ViewBag` and `Session` don't seem to be helpful. My requirement is to count ratings of individual products respect to their product id and that should be returned with the same Ajax call. In the Index method, I am doing the following:

```
CountAll = db.Ratings.Where(c => c.ProductId == id).Count() //id - I am trying to pass from Ajax call
```

I hope, there would be a better way to do this and currently struggling with it.

**Note:** Thanks @Luqman and @Stephen Muecke. @Stephen Muecke Thanks for the call. I was making two Ajax calls for demo purpose and apology for the delay to update the post.

Here is the working sample right now:

[image: Star Rating]

Comment: Why on earth are you making 2 separate ajax calls?

Comment: Please see my updated post @Stephen Muecke. Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you use the session to get store the id. Please use a Model or Tempdata to store that id.

Comment: `TempData` **IS** `Session`! This is nonsense

Comment: And how would that help? The model wont exist in the 2nd call - it would have to be stored in `Session`! But OP's question does not make any sense anyway (making 2 separate calls when only one is needed)

Comment: @AT-2017 : Kindly edit this answer by which way you got the solution.